# IONIC-V3 : Wait page to pop before continue executing code

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I’m iterating over a JSON that contains some rules to build my page. The loop is something like this:

```
  flux.forEach(element => {
       this.navCtrl.push(element.pageName);
  });
```

My issue here is that I need to wait for this page to execute its action before call the next, this loop makes a stack. How can I make sort of a promise to wait the page to execute its duty before continue the loop?

Thank you all!

Comment: Do you find a solution ? I have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve promises in sequence, you can use `reduce()` as explained [here](https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84).

```
element.reduce((promise,item) => {
  return promise.then(() => { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        this.navCtrl.push(element.pageName);
        resolve();
    })
  })
},Promise.resolve())
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it out here :)